# RichEdit20A line selection mode similar to Notepad

Tags: windows, winapi, controls

I'm trying to change the way [RichEdit20A](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787873.aspx) Windows control selects line so it's similar to how it works in Notepad.

By default, if I select a line (e.g. Shift-End), then all the characters and the end of line is selected:

```
Sample text
^^^^^^^^^^^^ <- this is the selection
```

In Notepad it selects just the text:

```
Sample text
^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As a result, pressing delete (or backspace) in RichEdit20A control removes the line while in Notepad it just removes the text and keeps the line empty.

Is there any simple way (other than handling selection on my own) to configure the RichEdit20A control to keep formatting but make the line selection to work like in Notepad?

Comment: Notepad doesn't use a `RICHEDIT` control (WordPad does), it uses a standard multi-line `EDIT` control instead.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know such a setting to influence the RTF control. But pressing Shift+End is a key input that is possible to trap with a `WM_KEYDOWN` handler, when you subclass the control.

You can use `EM_LINEINDEX` with -1 to get the current line start index.

Now with this index you can use `EM_LINELENGTH`.

Get the current selection (`EM_GESTEL`) and now you are free to use `EM_SETSEL` with the values you like to extend it.

Comment: I'm looking for a configuration-only solution or a confirmation that there's no such setting. Thanks anyway.